# Mysql BLOB performance degradation after hitting "a limit" (MyISAM)

Tags: mysql, performance, blob

I have a rather small mysql DB in which I store an handful of pretty small images (320x480), it all behaved really well until recently, the table size is about 1.5Gb and there are about 34,000 records. At that point...

...All of a sudden the performance degradated by a factor of 100.

It looks like the DB has hit a rock hard limit and it can't cope with it anymore.

Anyone experienced anything like it?

(Please don't suggest to move the images off the DB on the filesystem, we have decided to do that with the next version of the software)

Comment: Please provide a query that you are executing, as well as the table structure and indexes, so that we could help.

Comment: Forgot to add a really really strange behavior, if I access rows with a low id (the ID's are auto-incremented) the performances are really good, it's only when trying to accessing "latest" rows which causes the problem. (I'd say the "newest" 30% the table exhibit this issue)

Comment: table structure is this:

Comment: table structure is this: 

id  int(11)   PRI  auto_increment
image  longblob
thumbnail  longblob  
orientation  tinyint(4)    
user_id  int(11)  
property_id  int(11)  
last_change  int(11)
Example query:

Slow:
SELECT image FROM mytable WHERE property_id = 30000;

Fast:
SELECT image FROM mytable WHERE property_id = 1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible reason is that your query is not using indexes. When table was rather small, it was not a problem, but a bigger it gets, the tougher it is  for MySQL to get your data.

Check if column property_id is indexed. To speed up your query you can add covering index - (`property_id`, `image`)

You can see if your query uses indexes and more useful info by adding `EXPLAIN` to your query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT image FROM mytable WHERE property_id = 30000
```

Comment: Thanks, adding index to property_id only fixed the slowness. That was really noob from me :)

Answer (score 0):

I am quite certain that the database has started utilizing the disk instead of memory to do an operation. This operation could very well be to store data to temporary tables. Store indexes on disk in instead etc. Figure out what it is, and you solution will be a lot simpler to find.

The performance degration of 1 to 100 would fit with the speed difference between memory and disk.

Answer (score 0):

Do not create an index on the BLOB field, it is useless (and MySQL won't allow it).

Do you have proper indexes ? ie in this case, (property_id) ?...

Comment: Thank you, you were right, it was just a problem with indexes, I didnt put an index on a blob, at least I was aware of that! :)